# Python dictionaries vs C++ std:unordered_map (cython) vs cythonized python dict

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, cython, unordered-map

I was trying to measure the performance between python dictionaries, cythonized python dictionaries and cythonized cpp std::unordered_map doing only a init procedure. If the cythonized cpp code is compiled I thought it should be faster than the pure python version. I did a test using 4 different scenario/notation options:

- Cython CPP code using std::unordered_map and [Cython book notation](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033431.do) (defining a pair and using insert method)
- Cython CPP code using std::unordered_map and python notation (map[key] = value)
- Cython code (typed code) using python dictionaries (map[key] = value)
- Pure python code

I was expecting see how cython code outperforms pure python code, but in this case there is not improvement. Which could be the reason? I'm using Cython-0.22, python-3.4 and g++-4.8.

I got this exec time (seconds) using timeit:

- Cython CPP book notation -> 15.696417249999968
- Cython CPP python notation -> 16.481350984999835
- Cython python notation -> 18.585355018999962
- Pure python -> 18.162724677999904

Code is here and you can use it:

```
cython -a map_example.pyx
python3 setup_map.py build_ext --inplace
python3 use_map_example.py
```

map_example.pyx

```
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
from libcpp.pair cimport pair

cpdef int example_cpp_book_notation(int limit):
    cdef unordered_map[int, int] mapa
    cdef pair[int, int] entry

    cdef int i

    for i in range(limit):
        entry.first = i
        entry.second = i
        mapa.insert(entry)
    return 0

cpdef int example_cpp_python_notation(int limit):
    cdef unordered_map[int, int] mapa
    cdef pair[int, int] entry

    cdef int i

    for i in range(limit):
        mapa[i] = i

    return 0


cpdef int example_ctyped_notation(int limit):
    mapa = {}
    cdef int i
    for i in range(limit):
        mapa[i] = i
    return 0
```

setup_map.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

import os

os.environ["CC"] = "g++"
os.environ["CXX"] = "g++"


modules = [Extension("map_example",
                 ["map_example.pyx"],
                 language = "c++",
                 extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
                 extra_link_args=["-std=c++11"])]

setup(name="map_example",
     cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
     ext_modules=modules)
```

use_map_example.py

```
import map_example

C_MAXV = 100000000
C_NUMBER = 10

def cython_cpp_book_notation():
    x = 1
    while(x<C_MAXV):
        map_example.example_cpp_book_notation(x)
        x *= 10

def cython_cpp_python_notation():
    x = 1
    while(x<C_MAXV):
        map_example.example_cpp_python_notation(x)
        x *= 10

def cython_ctyped_notation():
    x = 1
    while(x<C_MAXV):
        map_example.example_ctyped_notation(x)
        x *= 10


def pure_python():
    x = 1
    while(x<C_MAXV):
        map_a = {}
        for i in range(x):
            map_a[i] = i
        x *= 10
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit

    print("Cython CPP book notation")
    print(timeit.timeit("cython_cpp_book_notation()", setup="from __main__ import cython_cpp_book_notation", number=C_NUMBER))


    print("Cython CPP python notation")
    print(timeit.timeit("cython_cpp_python_notation()", setup="from __main__ import cython_cpp_python_notation", number=C_NUMBER))


    print("Cython python notation")
    print(timeit.timeit("cython_ctyped_notation()", setup="from __main__ import cython_ctyped_notation", number=C_NUMBER))

    print("Pure python")
    print(timeit.timeit("pure_python()", setup="from __main__ import pure_python", number=C_NUMBER))
```

Comment: Can you put a timer just around the loop of interest?

Comment: I found a problem in pure python loop, I fixed and update both time and code. Anyway, it is still faster than cython?. I will add timing in the loops of interest

Answer (score 3):

My timings from your code (after correcting that python *10 indent :) ) are

```
Cython CPP book notation
21.617647969018435
Cython CPP python notation
21.229907534987433
Cython python notation
24.44413448998239
Pure python
23.609809526009485
```

Basically everyone is in the same ballpark, with a modest edge for the CPP versions.

Nothing special about my machine, the usual Ubuntu 14.10, 0.202 Cython, 3.42 Python.

Comment: You're right. I re-run the code and I updated exec time in the post. Maybe in order to see some differences is necessary to operate the maps values (find a specific key, operate on map's values, etc.).

Comment: So, don't bother using cpp's `unordered_map` at all?

Comment: @avocado Python's dict is already highly optimized. There's no reason to.

Comment: What about memory usage?

Comment: @kezzos: You're welcome to test it, but amusingly, it's probably not *much* worse for Python; sure, each Python  `int` (if it's 30 bits or less) is (on 64 bit builds) 28 bytes, and you're storing a pointer (8 more bytes) to them in the `dict`. On the other hand, Python `dict`s use a single contiguous buffer with open addressing, vs. `std::unordered_map` which uses buckets that separately allocate the storage for the contents of each bucket (if I'm reading the spec correctly, it's essentially required to use linked lists). The node allocations negate some of C++'s advantage storing the `int`s.

Comment: And if all the Python `int`s involved are cached `int`s (implementation detail which values are cached; CPython has been caching -5 to 256), then you're only paying the cost of the pointers; the cost of the pointers, 8 bytes a piece, is likely similar to the cost of a structure containing a single forward pointer and the `std::pair<int, int>` (8 + 4 + 4) bytes. So *very* close when the numbers are small (Python might even win, barely, though of course C++ could use `uint8_t` or `int16_t` or whatever to shave bytes), and Python losing by a bit when the numbers are larger.