# Is it possible to use a Cython Extension Type in a nogil section?

Tags: python, cython

I have created a Cython Extension Type and I would like to use it in a nogil context. But the compiler always throws an error. Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
  1 # cython: language_level=3
  2 
  3 from cython.parallel import prange
  4 
  5 cdef class C1:
  6 
  7     cdef public:
  8         int val
  9 
 10     def __cinit__(self, value):
 11         self.val = value
 12 
 13 def iterate_C1():
 14 
 15     cdef int i
 16     cdef int N = 4
 17     cdef C1 c1_i
 18 
 19     # This compiles fine
 20     c1 = C1(4)
 21     print(f'c1.val={c1.val}')
 22 
 23     # But this doesn't
 24     with nogil:
 25         for i in prange(N):
 26             c1_i = C1(i)
```

I get a number of exceptions but they all look like this:

```
Compiling c_one.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing c_one.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    print(f'c1.val={c1.val}')

    # But this doesn't
    with nogil:
        for i in prange(N):
            c1_i = C1(i)
           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

c_one.pyx:26:12: Assignment of Python object not allowed without gil

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    print(f'c1.val={c1.val}')

    # But this doesn't
    with nogil:
        for i in prange(N):
            c1_i = C1(i)
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

c_one.pyx:26:21: Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil
```

So is it not possible to use Cython Extension Types in a nogil context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely cannot create instances of `cdef` extension types inside a `nogil` block. They are ultimately Python objects and that requires reference counting (including in some non-obvious places, such as the type object), allocation of Python-managed memory, and deallocation of the previous contents of `ci`, including calling its destructor.

You should be able to access their `cdef members` (e.g. `val` for this class) and call their `cdef` functions that are marked as `nogil`.