# is nogil safe when accessing cython extension type members

Tags: cython

From [a similar question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050330/15534181):

> You should be able to access [an extension type's] cdef members [inside a nogil block]... and call their cdef functions that are marked as nogil.

However, the [cython documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html) disagrees:

> After the GIL is released, any operation that involves python objects must first reacquire the GIL.

I assume "python object" includes cython extension types. This leads me to think that the following pseudo code is not safe, since it includes a race condition caused by modifying a python object without the GIL:

```py
def function(ExtensionType arg):
    with nogil:
        # long running task
        # modify arg's member

arg = ExtensionType()
function(arg)
# access arg's member

# (alternatively, accessing and modifying the member could be swapped, with the same issue)
```

I've expanded this into actual code to illustrate my confusion:

```py
cimport cytime

cdef class Tester:
    cdef int val

    def get_val(self):
        return self.val

    def set_val(self):
        print("1: GIL acquired by set_val")
        with nogil:
            cytime.sleep(0.1) # give me the GIL later, I'm not ready for it yet
            self.val = 1
        print("3: GIL reacquired by set_val")

t = Tester()
t.set_val()
print("2: val should be 0, but actually is: " + str(t.get_val()))
```

I expected the program's execution to follow: 1, 2, 3. However, here is the output:

```
1: GIL acquired by set_val
3: GIL reacquired by set_val
2: val should be 0, but actually is: 1
```

Can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Comment: Surely `val` should be 1? Because that's what you set it to. It is safe (... I'll give an answer showing why later hopefully....). But I think you're *really* confused about what the GIL does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing/writing to `self.val` without the GIL is fine. You don't need to do any reference-counting for `self` (because you already have a reference to it, and you don't need another one) and you don't need to do any reference counting for `val` because it's a C `int`. You can actually do a reasonable amount on `cdef class` instances without the GIL (e.g. access `nogil` `cdef` methods).

Cython does generally block you from doing things that require the GIL in a `nogil` block (it isn't perfect, but generally it's reasonably thorough).

Note that if you chose to access `.val` from multiple threads then you may well have a race condition, and this is entirely your own fault. All I mean by "safe" is that the Python reference counting state doesn't get corrupted.

---

You seem to have a huge misunderstand of what a `nogil` block does though, and are viewing it as something similar to a coroutine!?

All that happens when you release the GIL is it allows lets *other* Python thread you have run. The thread that is processing `set_val` continues in logical order: it stops and waits for a bit, it sets the value, it waits to re-acquire the GIL, it prints statement-3, it returns to the global scope, it prints statement-2.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, a `cdef class` instance is refcounted, hence needs to be GIL-protected.