# pybind11 c++ unordered_map 10x slower than python dict?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I exposed a c++ `unordered_map<string, int>` to python, and it turned out this map is 10x slower than python's `dict`.

See code below.

```
// map.cpp file
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::unordered_map<std::string, int>);

PYBIND11_MODULE(map, m) {
    // map
    py::bind_map<std::unordered_map<std::string, int>>(m, "MapStr2Int");
}
```

On MacOS, compile it with this cmd:

```
c++ -O3 -std=c++14 -shared -fPIC -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) map.cpp -o map$(python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

Finally, compare with python `dict` in ipython:

```
In [20]: import map

In [21]: c_dict = map.MapStr2Int()

In [22]: for i in range(100000):
    ...:     c_dict[str(i)] = i
    ...:

In [23]: py_dict = {w:i for w,i in c_dict.items()}

In [24]: arr = [str(i) for i in np.random.randint(0,100000, 100)]

In [25]: %timeit [c_dict[w] for w in arr]
59 µs ± 2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit [py_dict[w] for w in arr]
6.58 µs ± 87.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As seen, `c_dict` is much much slower than python version `py_dict`.

Why and how to improve?

Comment: Not sure what your question is? If `std::unordered_map` is slower don't use it?

Comment: It seems that it is pybind11's fault as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268914/python-dictionaries-vs-c-stdunordered-map-cython-vs-cythonized-python-dict shows that they are roughly equal. On pybind's github many issues have been raised on your question: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1227 and https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/2005 etc. Idk if this helps

Comment: I would expect that pybind11 needs to allocate new memory to construct `std::string` objects for passing to the `unordered_map`. The python version doesn't need to do that.

Comment: @IainShelvington no, I was expecting the perf is not slower than py's dict, wonder if any tricks I missed.

Comment: @Yolomep Thanks for the links, looks relevant.

Comment: @user17732522 I see, that sounds true then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing a native dictionary implementation (the one from the Python Standard Library) and a pybind wrapped one. I would bet a coin that a C++ program directly using `std::unordered_map` is certainly faster than the equivalent one, written in Python and using a `dict`.

But it is not what you are doing here. Instead of that, you ask `pybind` to generate a wrapper that will convert Python types into C++ ones, call the C++ standard library class methods and then convert back the result into a Python type. Those convertions are likely to require allocation and deallocation and will indeed take some time. Moreover, `pybind` is a very clever (hence complex) tool. You cannot expect it to generate code that would be as much optimized as direct calls using the Python API.

Unless you intend to use a specially optimized algorithm for the hashing function, you will not be able to write a C or C++ code that will be faster than the standard library, because the builtin types are already coded in C language. At most, you should be able to be as fast as the standard library if you mimic it and directly use the [Python/C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html).

Comment: I think you should take the plunge and test it. My results corroborate what OP is saying. pydict is highly optimized and beats std:unordered_map for integers, small strings and strings.

Comment: @Jellyboy Thank you both here! Frankly speaking, this really makes me very confused on `pybind11`, my initial motivation is just to re-write some python functions using c++, so that I could get better perf, but those functions requires some dicts, so I have to replace the py dicts with c++ maps, then I got this results. very upset though.